# Using Powershell to export to CSV with columns

Tags: powershell, csv, export

I am trying to do a simple script that pulls in the name of the file and the contents of said text file into a CSV file. I am able to pull in all of the information well enough but it's not splitting up into different columns in the CSV file. When I open up the CSV file in excel everything is in the first column, and I need the two bits of information separated into separate columns. So far my working code is as follows:

```
$Data = Get-ChildItem -Path c:path -Recurse -Filter *.txt |
where {$_.lastwritetime -gt(Get-Date).addDays`enter code here`(-25)}

$outfile = "c:path\test.csv" 
rm $outfile

foreach ($info in $Data) {
    $content = Get-Content $info.FullName
    echo "$($info.BaseName) , $content" >> $outfile
}
```

I figured out how to seperate the information by rows but I need it by columns. I'm new to powershell and can't seem to get past this little speed bump. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Output:

```
Itm# , TextContent

Itm2 , NextTextContent
```

What I need:

```
Itm# | Text Content | 

Itm2 | NextTextContent |
```

Comment: I _really_ want to see some sample output. There is a couple of ways to interpret what your output is supposed to look like.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to post a pic of the output yet. As of now though it is showing up in the same column with the comma in between the data. what i need is for the data to be separated by column....

Comment: If your data is already comma delimeted I don't see an issue here? When you open in notepad does it look correct? You might just be doing an incorrect text import in Excel.

Comment: I open it as a CSV in excel and it puts everything in the first column as shown above with the comma separating the info. I keep looking everywhere to find out how to separate my info into columns and everyone keeps saying its done by the comma's but it's not separating for me...

Comment: That does not answer my question. What does it look like in notepad?

Comment: When opened in notepad it opens with the same as it does in excel. With everything on one line separated by the comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for a few syntactical errors your code appears to be working as expected. I worry if you are having issues in Excel with you text import. I touched up your code a bit but it is functionally the same as what you had.

```psh
$Data = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp" -Recurse -Filter *.txt |
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).addDays(-25)}

$outfile = "C:\temp\test.csv" 
If(Test-Path $outfile){Remove-Item $outfile -Force}

foreach ($info in $Data) {
    $content = Get-Content $info.FullName
    "$($info.BaseName) , $content" | Add-Content $outfile
}
```

I don't know what version of Excel you have but look for the text import wizard.

Comment: Thanks Matt! I'm still new to Powershell, and I've gone through and adjusted my code to fix the syntax error differences between my code and yours, and it seemed to have fixed the problem. Everything is now in the proper columns!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\path -Recurse -Filter *.txt | 
  Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-25) } | ForEach-Object {
  New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    "Itm#" = $_.FullName
    "TextContent" = Get-Content $_.FullName
  } | Select-Object Itm#,TextContent
} | Export-Csv List.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel will treat the data in csv files which are delimited bij the ; as a single columns.
I always use the -delimiter switch on export-csv or convertto-csv to set this as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using Out-File instead of Export-Csv.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).